# How to paste rows by value in excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that copies rows from another sheet to the current sheet at a given location.
ws2 and ws3 are worksheets.

```
ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(4, 1), ws3.Cells(4,2)).Copy ws2.Cells(2, 2)
```

How do I change this code to paste only the values of the cells? Current working code copies cells with formulas. I would like to know how to pass pasteSpecial parameters as below ?

```
ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(4, 1), ws3.Cells(4,2)).Copy ws2.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial = xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it into two lines and use a parenthesis rather than an `=` sign.

```
ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(4, 1), ws3.Cells(4,2)).Copy 
ws2.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: Fantastic . . .!